# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.simpletest.mapper.PersonMapper' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Error apears when runing the application :
**Consider defining a bean of type 'com.test.simpletest.mapper.PersonMapper' in your configuration.**

**EntityMapper:**

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {
    D toDTO(E entity);

    E toDAO(D dto);
}
```

**PersonMapper :**

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper extends EntityMapper<PersonDTO, Person> {
}
```

**PersonService:**

```
public interface PersonService {
    List<Person> getAllPersons();
    Person createPerson(Person person);
}
```

**PersonImpl:**

```
@Service
public class PersonImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    private PersonMapper personMapper;

    public PersonImpl(PersonRepository personRepository, PersonMapper personMapper) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
        this.personMapper = personMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public Person createPerson(Person person) {
        return  personRepository.save(person);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@Mapper` to `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. Then it will be correctly used by spring as a bean.